# After added a simple fmt.Println in "for {select }" structure the CPU usage is quite different , why?

Tags: go

Encounter a confused situation :
let's say we have a `for { select }` function which is written in Go.
Here the code below:

```
package main
//import "fmt"
func main(){

  for {
    select {

      default:
      _=1                     1. first situation 
      // fmt.Sprint("aa")     2. second situation 
          }
  }
}
```

while in the first situation the cup usage shows below:
[image]
in the second situation the cpu usage shows below:
[image]

I guess something happened in fmt.Println .
May be related to the mechanism of Go's fmt realization?
Not quite sure how it happens by using all the CPUs?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just a guess, but I think this has less to do with how fmt is implemented than with the fact that situation 1. does nothing and therefore, I assume, is optimized away by the compiler, together with the select statement since it as well does nothing, resulting in a `for {}` (an infinite loop) which I think is indicated by the single cpu 100% usage. Try it, remove the body of the loop and I think you should see approximately the same cpu stats.

Comment: .. In situation 2., the contents of the loop aren't optimized away since you have actual code that does something, that results in some output. Now, how a single `select` statement, with only a `default` case results in all cpus being used relatively equally I do not know. Don't know whether it is something you can attribute to `select`'s implementation or to Go's implementation in general.

Comment: Reasoning about unsensible code is basically useless.

Comment: @mkopriva  yes . I want to know in which situation the  cpus being used relatively equally . Try to find out it .

Answer (score 2):

My guess: In the first statement go's scheduler can't work. Go's scheduler is semi cooperative, and only works at certain points. Like function calls for example.

In an infinite loop with no function calls the scheduler has no chance to kick in..

Comment: try to add a common function call in the default section but cpu still take 100% . seems not that problem .

Comment: A small function call may be inlined.